# How can you dynamically alter global style components in React?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, react-component

When using styled components, is it possible to conditionally change global CSS properties (such as background-color)?

I'm using styled-components, but notice the following never triggers a re-render:

```
return (
  <>
    { changeColor? <GlobalStyleWhite/> : <GlobalStyleBlack/> }
    ...
  </>
)
```

Where `GlobalStyleXXX` is a `const GlobalStyleXXX = createGlobalStyle` derivative.